# How can I add components before tokenizer in spaCy pipline?

Tags: python, spacy

I want to preprocess string before passing it to the tokenizer.

For example, add an capitalizer before tokenizer.

```
"apple" -> "APPLE" -> doc
```

In other words, I want to put this component in front of the tokenizer in pipeline.

```py
def capitalizer(text: str) -> str:
  return text.upper()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to add a component before the tokenizer in the pipeline because the tokenizer has a special status as the initial component that takes a string and returns a Doc. (All other components take Docs and return Docs.) In general, I think it would be best to preprocess your texts outside of spacy.

However, you can create a custom tokenizer that does some preprocessing, since all you need is a component that takes a string and returns a Doc. It's pretty easy to modify a pipeline temporarily, but it's harder to get the modifications integrated enough that it can be saved to disk if you want to save and reload the model. This is a minimal version that can't be saved to disk:

```
import spacy

class CustomTokenizer():
    def __init__(self, tokenizer):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
    def __call__(self, string):
        return self.tokenizer(string.upper())

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.tokenizer = CustomTokenizer(nlp.tokenizer)
doc = nlp(u"hello-world.")
print([t.text for t in doc])
# ['HELLO', '-', 'WORLD', '.']
```